# How do I create a mysql dump file in kubernetes pod with java

Tags: java, mysql, kubernetes

I want to create a dump file from a mysql database in kubernetes pod with java.
I tried the following code with kubernetes-java-client library:

```
Process proc = exec.exec(ns, podName, new String[] { "mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-padmin", "wordpress", ">", "/root/wordpress.sql" },true);
proc.waitFor();
```

but this does not create the dump file in requested directory inside the pod.
I also tried to run kubectl exec and create dump file :

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr;
pr=run.exec("kubectl exec "+podName+" -n"+" "+ns +" -- mysqldump -u root -padmin wordpress > /root/wordpress.sql");
pr.waitFor();
BufferedReader errinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
String line;
   if ((line = errinput.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
```

result of this code should create the dump file in /root/wordpress.zip in my host and not in pod but this does not create it either.

I have the exact same problem for restoring a dump file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a solution , I created a script inside the container with following content :

```
mysqldump -u root -padmin wordpress > /root/wordpress.sql
```

then i set the permission 777 on this script:

```
chmod 777 /root/mysql.sh
```

then i run this script inside my code:

```
Process proc2 = exec.exec(ns, podName , new String [] {"sh", "/root/mysql.sh"} , true);
proc2.waitFor();
```